# How can I use awk to calculate sum and replace column in file

Tags: awk

I'm new to the site and to the programming world and I hope you have time to help me.
My problem is as follows: I have a file with several columns. In the 2nd column there are values. I'm tring to calculate the sum of each values to a given number and to replace the second column with a new column containing the results of the sum.
Here an example of my input:

```
A B C
x 1 t
y 2 u
z 3 v
```

I want to sum values in B column to 5 and obtain an output like the one below:

```
A B C
x 6 t
y 7 u
z 8 v
```

The code I tried unsucesfully is

```
zcat my_file.vcf.gz| tail -n +49 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $0, $2+5}'>my.output.vcf
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$2+=5}1'
```

Here, `$2+=5` will add `5` to Filed 2 value, and `1` will trigger the display of the record (row, line, same as `print $0`).

See [an online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/3pwwfU):

```
#!/bin/bash
s='A    B   C
x   1   t
y   2   u
z   3   v'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$2+=5}1' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
A   5   C
x   6   t
y   7   u
z   8   v
```

Answer (score 2):

We could avoid using `tail` since printing of lines from 49th line could be handled within `awk` itself. Also you need to add value in 2nd field and then you could print the whole line itself by `print` command.

Important point, as per OP's sample if 2nd field is having alphabets then need NOT to add `5` in it, so taken care of that condition too here.

```
zcat my_file.vcf.gz | 
awk '
  BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
  FNR>=49{
    $2=($2~/[a-zA-Z]/?$2:$2+5)
    print
  }
' > my.output.vcf
```

Comment: Is fine to use the FNR argument, thanks, unfortunately your code gives me an error as follows: "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near print"

Comment: @MrGoodcat, honestly it worked fine for me when I tested it, which o.s you are on?

Comment: @RavinerdSingh13 I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Anyway I will try further to check if I've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Another form for clarity:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {print $1, $2+5, $3}'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} NR == 1 {print $0}   NR > 1 {print $1,($2+5),$3;}'
```

output:

```
A       B       C
x       6       t
y       7       u
z       8       v
```

Answer (score 0):

Maube this can help you:

```
cat file | awk '{if (NR > 1 && $2 = ($2+5)) 
                     print $0;
                else print $0;}'
```

Answer apply to your code:

```
zcat my_file.vcf.gz| tail -n +49 | awk '{if (NR > 1 && $2 = ($2+5)) print $0; else print $0;}' > my.output.vcf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat boo
A       B       C
x       1       t
y       2       u
z       3       v

cat boo | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $1, $2+5, $3}  $2 !~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print} '
A       B       C
x       6       t
y       7       u
z       8       v
```